# Selenium click not working in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, instagram, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to click on the anchor tag on instagram's page which says log in. Here is my code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://instagram.com')
login_elem = browser.findElement(By.xpath('//p/a[text() = "Log in"'))
login_elem.click()
```

The browser opens however the element is not clicked. I have tried various other xpaths and none worked. [Here is the image for the Instagram source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4G35.png)

Comment: browser object which is WebDriver has `find_element` method and also By.xpath should be written as `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text() = "Log in"]')`

Read about the selenium api's

Comment: That xpath is missing a closing `]`.

Comment: Fixed both of those however still not clicking the link.

Comment: @munyb What error you are getting ? Please share error stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i tried on my local system and it worked

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\cs\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[text() = "Log in"]')
# added this step for compatibility of scrolling to the view
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", a)
a.click()
```

Corrected the XPATH and other changes.Please note executable path should be replaced with your path.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I believe the issue was me needing to import By?... Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Xpath

```
.//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a
```

or CSS Selector

```
.izU2O>a
```

or Link Text

```
Log in
```

Comment: Have tried all of these and none work for some reason. Just opens the browser and nothing happens. Then closes after period of time.

Comment: what is your chrome version and chrome driver version?

Comment: 66.0.3359.18 and web driver 2.39 I believe

Comment: can you initialize driver with - webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver exe")

Comment: Changed to this, browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver") still nothing.

Comment: @munyb  Did you add full path of driver including .exe ?

Comment: On a Mac so don't have .exe extensions

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Log in")))
element.click()
```